# Pass host as a variable from role to next role

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a long playbook with a number of roles defined. Now i have a requirement for one role i need to pass the host as a variable which will be defined on an earlier role.
eg playbook

```
    ---
- name: task1
  hosts: app1
  gather_facts: no
  any_errors_fatal: true
  roles:
    - role-1

- name: task2
  hosts: "{{ host }}" 
  any_errors_fatal: true
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - role-2
```

My role-1

```
---
     - name: setting the var
       set_fact:
          host: "app2"

     - debug:
          var: host
```

My role-2

```
---
      - debug:
              var: host
      - name: do something
        file:
          path: /home/ec2-user/dir1
          state: directory
          mode: '0755'
```

however, when I try to run my playbook my role-2 gets skipped because no hosts matched. can someone point me on how to get this setup working.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want is [`add_host:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/add_host_module.html) and then set the newly created or assigned group as the `hosts:` the 2nd play:

```
- hosts: app1
  tasks:
  - add_host:
      name: app2
      groups:
      - my-group

- hosts: my-group
  tasks:
  - debug: var=ansible_host
```